# How can I assert that the argument only contains listed integers in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion, int, arguments

I have a method in Python and I only want to accept integers listed or singular, how can I define this?

```
def autoInt(integers):
    assert int(integers)
    assert len(integers) > 0
```

This fails as I cannot have a list. I'm sure it's something easy.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Edit: I have been tasked so that this method can ONLY accept integers in a list.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `assert` for this? The  `assert` statement is used to verify that your program logic is correct, it's not for validating data. So the assertion should only get raised if something happens which should _never_ happen if your program logic is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what passes as an integer by your definition. For example, do instances of `bool` count? Does the float `1.0`?

Anyway - you can combine the `all` builtin with a generator expression.

```
>>> a = [1,2,True]
>>> all(isinstance(x, int) for x in a)
True
```

As a sidenote: rigorously checking the argument types in not something Python programmers do when there's no specific reason. A better approach is usually to write clear docstrings and/or type hints.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957034/python-type-hints-specifying-a-type-to-be-a-list-of-numbers-ints-and-or-floats) is an answer which explains how to do the latter. Apart from that, there's usually a "garbage in -> garbage (or error)" out mentality.

Comment: Thanks @timgeb. I have to write out a specification for the computational problem as well. Just wanted to get pre-conditions to include 'must be int'.

Answer (score 1):

You can test a list of integers like this:

```
assert(all(isinstance(item, int) for item in integers))
```

From [How to test if every item in a list of type 'int'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009589/how-to-test-if-every-item-in-a-list-of-type-int)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3.25]
>>> all(isinstance(item, int) for item in my_list)
False
>>> other_list = range(3)
>>> all(isinstance(item, int) for item in other_list)
True
>>>
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/6009630/6748523

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion