# Python typing: Creating Tuple type at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, mypy, python-typing

I want to create a type that is a tuple that contains 5 floats and an int. I can do this in the following way which works nicely.

```
from typing import Tuple

MyT = Tuple[float, float, float, float, float, int]
t: MyT = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5)
```

But if I want even more floats it will become annoying having to type the same over and over. Is there a way to create such a type in a parametrized way? I know that passing a tuple to Tuple[] works as well, i.e.

```
MyT = Tuple[(float, float, float, float, float, int)]
t: MyT = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5)
```

Therefore, I tried the following.

```
tup = ((float, ) * 5) + (int, )
MyT = Tuple[tup]

t: MyT = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5)
```

But this fails type checking with mypy. I guess it is because the tuple that is passed to Tuple[] is created only at runtime? Is there a similar way that would work?
Tested using Python 3.8.6 and MyPy 0.782.

Comment: You can use `Tuple[float, ...]` to accept any number of numeric values.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43957034/3282436) regarding whether to use `int`/`float` for the type parameter.)  It doesn't make sense to create type hints at runtime since they are designed for linters to validate pre-runtime.

Comment: it assumes all are float. there is int in the type.

Comment: Note, passing a tuple doesn't work "as well", it's already what you are doing here: `Tuple[float, float, float, float, float, int]`, i.e., the commas make the tuple, not the parentheses in `Tuple[(float, float, float, float, float, int)]`. In any case, what is it that you are trying to avoid, exactly? Why would you have to type this over-and-over, it looks like you are already using an alias, wouldn't you just use the alias over and over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify length of Sequence or List with Python typing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833822/specify-length-of-sequence-or-list-with-python-typing-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to automate the process of creating a tuple type hint or to create a tuple type where the number of items is parameterizable: you need to write out all five float types manually like you did in your first example.

Instead, I recommend you create a class instead:

```
class MyT:
    def __init__(self, a: List[float], b: int) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

You can express this class more compactly using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) if you prefer:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyTVersion2:
    a: List[float]
    b: int
```

Using either a class or dataclass should let you directly support storing a variable number of floats while also making the structure of your data easier for others to understand.

If it's important that you use specifically a tuple, I think the only options you have are to:

1. Settle for manually writing creating a new type alias for each kind of tuple you want to use.
2. Settle for something like `Tuple[Any, ...]`. Doing `Tuple[float, ...]` may also actually work for your specific example -- iirc mypy considers ints to be a subtype of floats.